# I'm using FMOD to create car engine sound with Unity but it didn't work, can you point out what went wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, fmod

I started using FMOD and Mathf.Lerp to create a sound engine for my game in Unity.

I'm using the examples in documents/Fmod VEHICLE and using custom physics for my car. When I run the game the audio doesn't work, and problem with fmod studio event emitter and listener in gameobject.

Actually im using and following this https://www.fmod.com/docs/2.02/unity/integration-tutorial.html
and I am new to FMOD and Unity, 50-50 you can say!

Can you please help me to run this and make it work with Max rpm and min and speed of car

This is the code I tried which has some issue:

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class ArcadeEngineAudio : MonoBehaviour
    {
        PG.CarController rezx;
        
        void Awake()
        {
            rezx = GetComponentInParent<PG.CarController>();
        }
        
        void Update()
        {

            float effectiveRPM = Mathf.Lerp(rezx.MinRPM, rezx.MaxRPM, rezx.CurrentSpeed);
            var emitter = GetComponent<FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter>();
            emitter.SetParameter("RPM", effectiveRPM);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use engine rpm, min rpm, and max rpm which doesn't work, even the current speed.

Answer (score 1):

First off, save your CPU cycles and grab the emitter in the Awake function, storing it as a member.

`var emitter = GetComponent<FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter>()`

Now, to answer your original question, your `rezx.CurrentSpeed` isn't a good input for the `Lerp` function as that is looking for a value in a 0 - 1 range. If you're tying it to RPM then that suggests you will need to add a basic implementation for gears.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Gear {

      public float minSpeed;
      public float maxSpeed;

    }
```

A min and max speed will allow you to calculate that 0 - 1 range with `CurrentSpeed`.

With this class declared, you can add `public List<Gear> gears;` to your `ArcadeEngineAudio` class, allowing you to create new gears in the Inspector of the component.

Once you have added your gears, you can use the `rezx.CurrentSpeed` to track which gear you're currently in based on the speed.

```
    void Update() {
        
        if(rezx.CurrentSpeed > gears[gearIndex].maxSpeed && gearIndex - 1 < gears.Count)
            gearIndex++;
            
        if(rezx.CurrentSpeed < gears[gearIndex].minSpeed && gearIndex > 0)
            gearIndex--;
        
        var min = gears[gearIndex].minSpeed;
        var max = gears[gearIndex].maxSpeed;
        
        var amount = (rezx.CurrentSpeed - min) / (max - min)
        
        float rpm = Mathf.Lerp(rezx.MinRPM, rezx.MaxRPM, amount);
        emitter.SetParameter("RPM", rpm);
    }
```

Comment: You need to cap gearIndex to between 0 and the size of your list, I'll edit the snippet to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I DID this in gears
and if i move the following

```
 var emitter = GetComponent<FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter>();
```

to the `Awake` function it throws an error, so I kept it in the `Update` function, which made the error go away.
However, the sounds don't work.
The gears are switching and the car works in the current gear but sounds are not playing.

Did I forget something to do?
Here is my work:

https://prnt.sc/-xMM39bM4SNw

https://prnt.sc/HaTexyaBSrjA

https://prnt.sc/xAn6vpcLE8tU

https://prnt.sc/ARcbBkP9OQaf

https://prnt.sc/z6-tJIM46Jou

Comment: any replay? bro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwxE1.png)

Hello I Tried ur code and the console showing
ArgumentOutOfRangeException Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

i fixed the errors comes to me in console needs gearindex int

did i missing something or the code wrong thanks in advice mr dan

icant solve the problem yet this all the code

```
    [Serializable]
public class Gear {

  public float minSpeed;
  public float maxSpeed;

}

public class ArcadeEngineAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
    PG.CarController uvc;
    public List<Gear> gears;
    public int gearIndex;

    void Awake()
    {
        uvc = GetComponentInParent<PG.CarController>();
    }
        
     void Update() {
    
    if(uvc.CurrentSpeed > gears[gearIndex].maxSpeed)
        gearIndex++;
        
    if(uvc.CurrentSpeed < gears[gearIndex].minSpeed)
        gearIndex--;
    
    var min = gears[gearIndex].minSpeed;
    var max = gears[gearIndex].maxSpeed;
    
    var amount = (uvc.CurrentSpeed - min) / (max - min);
    var emitter = GetComponent<FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter>();

    float rpm = Mathf.Lerp(uvc.MinRPM, uvc.MaxRPM, amount);
    emitter.SetParameter("RPM", rpm);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've altered the first snippet to prevent your error.

For the gears in the inspector, you need to add a minimum and maximum speed for each gear.

So say you have a car with 5 gears:


Index 0: {
   MinSpeed = 0
   MaxSpeed = 10
}

Index 1: {
   MinSpeed = 11
   MaxSpeed = 20
}

Index 2: {
   MinSpeed = 21
   MaxSpeed = 30
}

Index 3: {
   MinSpeed = 31
   MaxSpeed = 40
}

Index 4: {
   MinSpeed = 41
   MaxSpeed = 50
}

Comment: Should rather be a comment